# Can/will a proton escape the nucleus when a force is applied?

Tags: thermodynamics, electrostatics, atomic-physics, protons

Protons are contained within the nucleus of an atom. Protons carry a positive charge. With an electric field, we can exert a force on the proton.

Is it possible for the proton to escape the nucleus?

I ask because I'm wondering if it's possible to manipulate the movement of atoms, within an electrical conductor, using just an electric field. If the protons cannot escape the nucleus, and an electric field is exerting a force on the proton, this would result in movement of the atom that contains the proton (assuming the force exerted on the proton is "strong" enough).

If the above is correct, if we really could manipulate the movement of atoms within a conductor, that would mean we could control the temperature of the conductor (by controlling the moment of the atoms within the conductor).

I'm sure there are a lot of flaws in my understanding (above), please help me find them.

Comment: ...you can't move an atom with an electric field because an atom is *electrically neutral*. You can move ions and electrons. I'm not sure what you exact question about that is.

Comment: Sorry, @ACuriousMind, an atom is neutral but its parts are not, and the electric field may tear them apart in general.

Comment: @ACuriousMind is there such thing as a nucleus 'wall'? If an electric field is exerting a force on the proton, the proton would collide with the wall and result in movement of the atom?

Comment: You can strip all the electrons off an atom and the nucleus remains intact. Now, in a sufficiently (mind boggling) high field you might be able to influence the nucleus. The magnitude of such a field is left as an exercise...

Comment: ion ion collisions at LHC are nucleon nucleon collisions. http://home.cern/about/updates/2015/11/lhc-collides-ions-new-record-energy . It is the strong interaction that is studied . protons escape of course, and new forms of matter are studied

Comment: If you want to control the temperature of the conductor, you can, but not with moving a whole atom to another place, but by the moving electrons (which can freely move) that can 'collide' with the atoms to increase their kinetic energy. You can coil a wire (increasing the resistance) and attach to a battery.

Answer (score 2):

You can't have strong enough electric fields to tear the proton away from the nucleus but it is really a very subtle thing and the inability is just "by a little bit".

The strongest electric field that may exist is given by the [Schwinger limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwinger_limit). In $\hbar=c=1$ units, the field is $m_e^2 /q_e$. Once you reach this value, electron-positron pairs start to be spontaneously created in the electric field, and weaken the field. So it's a maximum value in some sense, just like the speed of light is a maximum speed.

When this electric field is multiplied by the proton's charge $|q_e|$, you get the force $m_e^2$ in Planck units. But the strong force between the proton and the neutrons in the nucleus is of order $m_{QCD}^2$, and that's larger because $m_{QCD}$ is larger than $m_e$ by some four orders of magnitude.

So the nuclei hold together by a larger force than what you can achieve by the strongest long-range static field in Nature, the electric field. That's a part of the reason why the force holding the nuclei together is known as the "strong [nuclear] force". Any electric field that may be added is small in comparison.

This reasoning only breaks down for very large nuclei because the strong force is a short-range force that only acts between neighboring protons and neutrons, roughly speaking, while the Coulomb force is a long-range force and the protons are piling up. That's why the energy encouraging the uranium to decay (fission) is actually mostly due to the Coulomb's repulsion between the protons. But for smaller nuclei and whenever you neglect the interaction of "many particles with many particles", the electric force is negligible relatively to the strong one.

Comment: Thank you! So if you used an electric field to exert a force on the proton, wouldn't the energy from the force be transferred to the nucleus, once the proton has reached the boundary of the nucleus? If so, would this not result in movement of the nucleus?

Comment: Yes, exactly, the electric force would perhaps "stretch the nucleus" a bit and made the protons "more likely to be in the front" but at the end, it would act on the whole nucleus as on a single positively charged particle and accelerate it. An electric force may be in principle enough to ionize an atom - tear the electron, however.

Comment: Right! So if the force from the electric field resulted in the movement of the nucleus, would that not mean we could move an atom with the electric field? (Once the nucleus reaches the atom boundary (if there is any such thing?), this would result in movement of the atom?)

Comment: Well, the atom by definition contains as many electrons as many protons in the nucleus, so the total charge is $Q=0$. So the electric force on the overall atom is zero. The force acts by pushing the nucleus to one side and the electrons to the other side. If the field becomes really strong, the electron(s) may be separated from the nucleus, and they are then accelerated in the opposite direction. It's meaningless to talk about the "boundary" of an atom. The boundary isn't sharp in any way - the atom occupies some rough space where the electrons have a high enough probability to be located.

Comment: If you really want some childish picture, it's OK to think that the atom is a bag with the nucleus normally in the center, the electric field may bring the nucleus towards the boundary of the bag, and if you increase the electric field further, the nucleus jumps out and the atom gets ionized. Well, this is really misleading in one respect, not only due to the fuzzy boundary of the atom: it's really the *electrons*, and not the nucleus, that will be torn apart (parts of the bag material), and they may be torn (ionized) one by one.

Comment: The "bag" is misleading because it makes you think that the nucleus is the most "flexible" part of the atom and the rest is there to stay. The truth is exactly the other way around. It's the electrons that are most affected by the external forces and that may be manipulated, torn away from the atom, and so on.